# XML deserialisation fails with nested classes (inner classes)

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, inner-classes, xml-deserialization, invalidoperationexception

**Edit**
I have a problem at **de**serialising an XML file, containing inner classes (or nested classes).

I have following class diagram:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "HM")]
    public class OwnClass : BaseClass{

    ...
    public OwnClass(){} // default constructor
    ...
    }
```

I have the following `_xmlMessageFormatter` declaration (based on `System.Messaging`):

```
this._xmlMessageFormatter = new System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter();
System.Type[] OwnTypes = new System.Type[30];
OwnTypes[0] = typeof(Baseclasses.OwnClass);                   /* TR */
...
this._xmlMessageFormatter.TargetTypes = OwnTypes;
```

**Edit: this is what the XML looks like:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<HM xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ID>124</ID>
    <TC>TR</TC>
</HM>
```

All of this is working fine.

Now I add a new class inside the definition of `OwnClass`:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "HM")]
    public class OwnClass : BaseClass {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "INS")]
        public ClassInside f_Inside;

        ...
        public OwnClass(){} // default constructor
        ...
        public class ClassInside{
        ...
        public class ClassInside(){}
            ...} // end of ClassInside
        } // end of OwnClass
```

I've also added the corresponding targettype:

```
OwnTypes [27] = typeof(BaseClasses.OwnClass.ClassInside); // the number of the array is correct.
```

**Edit: the XML file looks now as follows:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<HM xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ID>125</ID>
    <TC>TR</TC>
    <TR>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <CD>MOVE</CD>
    </TR>
</HM>
```

The `_xmlMessageFormatter` cannot handle the **de**serialisation, as you can see here:
Source code:

```
    Object temp;
    temp = this._xmlMessageFormatter.Read(message);
```

For getting more information, I've typed `? temp = this._xmlMessageFormatter.Read(message);` in the immediate window (I'm working with Visual Studio), this is what I get:

```
'temp = this._xmlMessageFormatter.Read(message)' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233079
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {"There was an error reflecting field 'f_Inside'."}
    Message: "There was an error reflecting type 'BaseClasses.AnotherClass'."
    Source: "System.Xml"
    StackTrace: "   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)\r\n   at 
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElement(TypeModel model, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace, RecursionLimiter limiter)\r\n   at 
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(Type type, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace)\r\n   at 
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)\r\n   at 
System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter.CreateTargetSerializerTable()\r\n   at 
System.Messaging.XmlMessageFormatter.Read(Message message)"
    TargetSite: {System.Xml.Serialization.TypeMapping ImportTypeMapping(System.Xml.Serialization.TypeModel, 
System.String, 
ImportContext, 
System.String, 
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributes, 
Boolean, 
Boolean, 
System.Xml.Serialization.RecursionLimiter)}
```

I have two issues with the error message:

- It mentions `f_Inside`. This looks correct, but I have used `f_Inside` as a general fieldname for all my classes, and the reason I mention this:
- It mentions `AnotherClass` while I have send a message of the form `OwnClass`.

=> I'm having serious doubts about the correctness of the error message. Is there anybody who knows what I can do now (or how the `_xmlFormatter` works?)

**Edit: added background**
All of this is part of a messaging service: one application is sending a message, the other one is receiving it (using the `System.Messaging.MessageQueue` objects). The serialisation/deserialisation is just a part of it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: xml Serializer when  inheriting a base class expect a 'type' attribute in the xml file and an Include types (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0).  Try taking your classes and insert dummy data and then serialize.  Compare your original xml against the serialize data.  The format of the xml must match.

Comment: Teach yourself.  Serialize data and compare to your xml file.  The must match.  It is easier to see what is wrong when serializing than with deserializing.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  Your question omits `BaseClass`.  E.g. If `BaseClass` also has a public field or property `f_Inside` that is serialized to `<INS ... >` then that might cause your problem.  An XML sample might also help.

Comment: @dbc: I can confirm that `BaseClass` does not have a property `f_Inside` and that the obtained XML files are correct. I've added the XML files as you requested.

Comment: @jdweng: sorry for the confusion, but my question is about **de**serialisation, not serialisation. I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I meant serialize.  The best way of testing deserialize is to serialize test data.  Then you can compare the serialized xml against actual xml to see difference.  Doing what I said you would of quickly seen the tag differences between "SA" and "SomeAttribute".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved and it had nothing to do with deserialisation of nested classes:

In one of my classes (`AgainAnotherClass`), I had following source code:

```
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "SA")]
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "SA")]
  public string SomeAttribute { get; set; }
```

(a typical case of Copy/Paste)
The fact that I had two lines with `XmlElement` caused the problem.

The exception looked as follows:

```
  InnerException: {"There was an error reflecting field 'f_Inside'."}
  Message: "There was an error reflecting type '<NameSpace>.AgainOtherClass'."
```

The `InnerException` made me believe that there was a problem with the nested class, while the `Message` spoke about a completely other class. I decided to follow the `InnerException`.
That was wrong! So, in case of C# exceptions where `InnerException` and `Message` contradict each other, first check the `Message`, then (maybe) the `InnerException`.